# Default mount options cause USB to mount in read-only

Tags: usb, mount, 17.10

When I plug USB stick, it is mounted in read-only mode. `dmesg` output:

```
[189999.758776]  sdc: sdc1
[189999.759811] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[190000.140329] FAT-fs (sdc1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
[190000.269130] FAT-fs (sdc1): error, corrupted directory (invalid entries)
[190000.269135] FAT-fs (sdc1): Filesystem has been set read-only
[190217.318154] FAT-fs (sdc1): error, corrupted directory (invalid entries)
```

Basically, because of some minor error it remounts disk as read-only. I believe this is due to default mount options being `errors=remount-ro`. I want to change those default options, but I cannot find relevant configs.

I don't want to add this particular usb stick to `/etc/fstab` list or to mount it manually.

Comment: Have you tried to check/repair the FAT file system? See this link, [Repair the partition table and file system of a pendrive](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986)

Comment: @sudodus, this happens often - I assume its windows messing up the file system. And I don't want to do it every time by hand

Comment: Does it happen also when you eject the USB drive safely (alias unmount it)? In that case, maybe you have no real choice. But you can create (if necessary get some help to create) a shellscript, that will run all the commands for you, so it will be rather convenient.

Comment: @sudodus, no, drives may be ejected in unsafe manner. I want issue to be resolved once, without need to run scripts or whatsoever.

Comment: You can create a bug report at Launchpad, http://launchpad.net/ and wait for a developer to fix the problem. (But if the linux developers think that it is caused by a bug in Windows, it will not be fixed.)

Comment: @sudodus, I am looking for a way to override default mounting options for my installation of ubuntu. Default options are not buggy, they are invalid for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75291/discussion-between-sudodus-and-andrei-r).